# Installing Spack on HPC System fails: <unknown file>

Tags: hpc, spack

I'm following [this tutorial](https://spack-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_basics.html) to try and install Spack on a large cluster running CentOS 7.

At the bootstrapping step `spack spec zlib` I get an error:

```
==> Error: <unknown file>:1: [ordereddict([('compiler', ordereddict([('spec', 'gcc@=4.8.5'), ('paths', ordereddict([('cc', '/bin/gcc'), ('cxx', '/bin/g++'), ('f77', '/bin/gfortran'), ('fc', '/bin/gfortran')])), ('flags', ordereddict()), ('operating_system', 'centos7'), ('target', 'x86_64'), ('modules', []), ('environment', ordereddict()), ('extra_rpaths', [])]))])] is not of type 'object'
```

I tried different Spack versions. I'm using default settings for the compilers, tried writing compilers.yaml, and set up a clean install multiple times. While `spack list` works, `spack compiler find` throws the same error. The compiler settings in this error are correct.

Can't find this error anywhere. Any help is highly appreciated!